# TabLayout Android Color Bug

Tags: android, android-tablayout

I have a tablayout in fragment which has its colors predefined in the xml.  When the fragment is initialised, the tablayout shows the right color.
 However in certain devices (Especially api 21 and above), the tablayout changes its color to white without any reason when some action happens in the fragment. I am nowhere touching the tablayout color through my code. Can someone explain why. Also, I noticed when keyboard comes up in the fragment for any user action, the tab layout color changes to white. Can activity resizing be a cause of this ? It seems when keyboard comes up, the tablayout background color seems to go away as if it has moved up or something.

[My Home with tab layout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/70AQM.jpg).

Comment: where you initialize to color which change dynamically?

Comment: The color is initialized in my xml declaration of tablayout. I am nowhere touching the color. However, tablayout changes its color whenever it whishes in api21+ devices.

Comment: are you use color using @color folder or by direct initialization of color code ??

Comment: I am using @color resource file to set tablayout color.

Comment: try once direct initialization.

Comment: What is direct initialization. Setting color directly with hex code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I resolved this issue by setting tablayout drawable xml's for selected and unselected states instead of using just background color from resources